# Appending items to a variadic function wrapper without reallocating a new slice

Tags: go, variadic-functions

Ok I need a small wrapper of fmt.Printf() for debugging conveniance :

1/ "too many arguments in call to fmt.Fprintln" :

```
func Debug (a ... interface{}) {
    if debug {
        fmt.Fprintln(out, prefix, sep, a...)
    }
}
```

2/ "name list not allowed in interface type" :

```
func Debug (a ... interface{}) {
    if debug {
        fmt.Fprintln(out, []interface{prefix, sep, a...}...)
    }
}
```

3/ Works, but feels wrong :

```
func Debug (a ... interface{}) {
    if debug {
        sl := make ([]interface{}, len(a) + 2)
        sl[0] = prefix
        sl[1] = sep
        for i, v := range a {
            sl[2+i] = v
        }

        fmt.Fprintln(out, sl...)
    }
}
```

Any ideas to avoid allocating extra memory ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just do two prints:

```
func Debug(a ...interface{}) {
    if debug {
        fmt.Fprint(out, prefix, sep)
        fmt.Fprintln(out, a...)
    }
}
```

If you believed you needed to make a single call to Fprint, you could do,

```
func Debug(a ...interface{}) {
    if debug {
        fmt.Fprint(out, prefix, sep, fmt.Sprintln(a...))
    }
}
```

Either way seems simpler that building a new slice.

Comment: This really seems to be the best way to do it, no allocating and not copying.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use `append` for a one-liner:

```golang
func Debug (a ...interface{}) {
    if debug {
        fmt.Fprintln(out, append([]interface{}{prefix, sep}, a...)...)
    }
}
```

Comment: That one line won't work. It's actually `fmt.Fprintln(out, append([]interface{}{prefix, sep}, a...)...)` (I couldn't edit the post)

Answer (score 4):

I would write:

```
func Debug(a ...interface{}) {
    if debug {
        aa := make([]interface{}, 0, 2+len(a))
        aa = append(append(aa, prefix, sep), a...)
        fmt.Fprintln(out, aa...)
    }
}
```

The allocation is only made in debug mode, so why is the number of `Debug` function allocations significant?

The Go `fmt` package is expensive because of its generality; it uses reflection, it allocates, and it does I/O. Why are the `Debug` function allocations relatively significant?

Have you considered using the [Go `log` package](http://golang.org/pkg/log/)?

Comment: len(aa) should be initially 0.

Comment: Alright thank's, I'll have a look at the log package, seems interesting.

To answer your question : it's not significant, really. It's more a general concern. Thank's to both of you for append() func though, didn't know about it and was wondering how to add elements to slices


@Atom why is that ? It's growing towards len(a)+2 anyway

Comment: For `aa := make([]interface{}, 2+len(a))`, `len(aa) = 2+len(a)` and `cap(aa) = 2+len(a)`.  For, `aa :+ make([]interface{}, 0, 2+len(a))`, `len(aa) = 0` and `cap(aa) = 2+len(a)`. append starts appending at `len(aa)`.

Answer (score 3):

Variadic arguments can be used as slices, so no need to allocate a new one:

```
func Debug(a ...interface{}) {
    if debug {
            a = append(a, 0)
            copy(a[1:], a[0:])
            a[0] = prefix + sep
            fmt.Fprintln(out, a...)
    }
}
```

See http://play.golang.org/p/xXEO58BJoA for a working example

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to avoid allocating extra memory.

The shortest and most efficient Go code seems to be:

```
func Debug (a ...interface{}) {
    if debug {
        b := make([]interface{}, 0, 2+len(a))
        b = append(b, prefix, sep)
        b = append(b, a...)
        fmt.Fprintln(out, b...)
    }
}
```

Minor note: In your 2nd example, you are missing a {}:

```
fmt.Fprintln(out, []interface{}{prefix, sep}...)
```